# Custom Tag implementation issue

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have customs tags as follows. repeat and heading tag have `doAfterBody` method implemented.Both of them extends BodyTagSupport class

```
        <csajsp:repeat reps="5">
                <LI>
                    <csajsp:heading bgColor="BLACK">
                        White on Black Heading
                    </csajsp:heading>
                </LI>
            </csajsp:repeat>
```

*Repeat tag Class*

```
    public void setReps(String repeats) {
              System.out.println("TESTING"+repeats);
                       //sets the reps variable.
    }
    public int doAfterBody() {
              System.out.println("Inside repeate tag"+reps);
            if (reps-- >= 1) {
              BodyContent body = getBodyContent();
              try {
                JspWriter out = body.getEnclosingWriter();
                System.out.println("BODY"+body.getString());
                out.println(body.getString());
                body.clearBody(); // Clear for next evaluation
              } catch(IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Error in RepeatTag: " + ioe);
              }
              return(EVAL_BODY_TAG);
            } else {
              return(SKIP_BODY);
            }
          }
```

*Class of Heading tag*

```
      public int doAfterBody()
          {
              System.out.println("inside heading tag");
              BodyContent body = getBodyContent();
              System.out.println(body.getString());
                try {
                  JspWriter out = body.getEnclosingWriter();
                  out.print("NEW TEXT");
                } catch(IOException ioe) {
                  System.out.println("Error in FilterTag: " + ioe);
                }
                // SKIP_BODY means I'm done. If I wanted to evaluate
                // and handle the body again, I'd return EVAL_BODY_TAG.
                return(SKIP_BODY);
          }
          public int doEndTag() {
                try {
                  JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
                  out.print("NEW TEXT 2");
                } catch(IOException ioe) {
                  System.out.println("Error in HeadingTag: " + ioe);
                }
                return(EVAL_PAGE); // Continue with rest of JSP page
              }
```

*Custom tag tld file is*

```
<taglib>
  <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
   <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
  <shortname>csajsp</shortname>
  <uri></uri>
  <tag>
    <name>heading</name>
    <tagclass>com.test.tags.HeadingTag</tagclass>
    <bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
     <attribute>
      <name>bgColor</name>
      <required>true</required> <!-- bgColor is required -->
    </attribute>
  </tag>
   <tag>
    <name>repeat</name>
    <tagclass>com.test.tags.RepeatTag</tagclass>
    <info>Repeats body the specified number of times.</info>
    <bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
    <attribute>
      <name>reps</name>
      <required>true</required>
      <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
</taglib>
```

The order in which SOP are printed is

1. Setter method of csajsp:repeat is called.
2. White on Black Heading is printed. ie doAfterBody of csajsp:heading tag is called.

I don't know why it is not calling `doAfterBody` of `csajsp:repeat` tag.

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Not enough information. We need to relevent parts of the TLD file, and we need to know which class/interface your tags are extending

Comment: Hi,I've updated the thread with sufficient information. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

What class do your tags extend?

The default behaviour of [TagSupport](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagSupport.java.html) is to return `SKIP_BODY`, which would skip processing of the tag body.

The default behaviour of [BodyTagSupport](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/BodyTagSupport.java.html) is to return `EVAL_BODY_BUFFERED`, which would process the tag body.

If you are implementing [BodyTag](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/BodyTag.html) yourself, then you need to make sure you override doStartTag correctly to indicate that the JSP body should be evaluated.